# Is there a different method to bind iOS ICommands in MvvmCross 3.0.14?

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross

The tutorial N=5 of the N+1 days of MvvmCross builds fine in Xamarin Studio when downloaded.  However, if I update the assemblies from 3.0.5 to 3.0.14, the iOS project no longer builds.  The error has to do with these two lines:

```
set.Bind(button).To(vm => vm.MyCommand);
set.Bind(button2).To(vm => vm.GoSecondCommand);
```

The error message is as follows:

> Cannot convert `lambda expression' to non-delegate type `string'

Has there been a change to the way this works?  The object browser shows the correct method taking a `Func<TSource, object>` but it seems that the compiler wants to use the `string` version.  The odd thing is that the two lines above it binding to regular properties work fine, but the `ICommand` binded stuff fails.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since N=5 was filmed, xamarin have added their own pcl support

As part of this support, you need to add a project reference for your Touch UI project to `System.Windows.dll` in the Assemblies part of Add Reference.

This System.Windows assembly contains a type forwarding definition of ICommand - and this should clear your compilation error

Comment: I have double-checked that I have System.Windows.dll, but still get this same exact error he was getting.  Do you have any pointers on where else I could look?  I have googled galore on this one.

Comment: For anyone else, if you can't get this to work, also compare your Nuget packages with the "PictureTaking" solution under the MvvmCross Tutorials (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials).  Somehow I had a package called just "MvvmCross" that I didn't need.  Once I removed that, it built fine.