# mvvmcross iOS Bind to list Cannot convert `lambda expression' to non-delegate type `string'

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross

I worked this out but I want to share because there doesn't seem to be an answer on SO or elsewhere.

My ViewModel has a list of models eg

```
private List<string> _people;
public List<string> People 
{
get { return this._people; }
    set { this._people = value; RaisePropertyChanged (() => People); }
}
```

When I try to bind to set.Bind the MvxStandardTableViewSource, the evil error above prevents compile:

```
var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(tableView, "People");
tableView.Source = source;
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, Core.ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.People);
```

**Cannot convert `lambda expression' to non-delegate type`string'**

The solution is to add a reference to your models library. Simple right? But not obvious because you don't have to do this for other mobile projects - Probably because iOS is doing compile time binding.

Comment: I think this is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342667/is-there-a-different-method-to-bind-ios-icommands-in-mvvmcross-3-0-14

Comment: Might be worth raising as a compiler request with Xam - although I think the compiler warning/error messages are "standard"

Comment: @Stuart When I was searching for the solution questions/203242667 didn't answer it for me - Although it does seem to be the same problem where the compiler doesn't know about the type being bound.

Comment: @Stuart the error comes from csc.exe I believe, so probably not easy to make it more informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add a reference to your models library.

Any type being bound in the iOS view has to have its assembly referenced by the iOS project..